# Zend: the controller is looking for the model inside the controllers folder

Tags: model, controller, zend-framework2

I have a problem, I can't seem to get out :

I have a controller that looks like this

```js
namespace Restapi\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->getAllCountries();
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function homeAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    protected function getAllCountries()
    {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
        $resultSetPrototype = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
        $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Restapi\Model\Country);
        $tableGateWay = new Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('country', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);

        $countryTable = new Model\CountryTable($tableGateWay);
        var_dump($countryTable->fetchAll());
    }

}
```

Which should be calling the "Country" class inside the "Restapi/Model" folder.

But I have an error when i try to use the method who calls the model:

> "Fatal error: Class 'Restapi\Controller\Restapi\Model\Country' not found in D:\Web\Code\ZendRest\module\Restapi\src\Restapi\Controller\AdminController.php on line 28".

Zend absolutely wants to look for the model in the Controller folder. Anyone knows why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR**: Add `use Restapi\Model\Country` to the top of the file (where the other `use` lines are), and change the way you're instantiating the class to just: `new Country`.

**Longer explanation**: This is just a PHP namespaces issue. At the top of the file you've declared the namespace `Restapi\Controller`, which tells PHP to assume any classes you subsequently use are within that namespace, unless you import them (with the `use` command), or reference them using via. the global namespace (class names that start with a backslash).

So, when you call `new Restapi\Model\Country`, what you're actually doing is `new \Restapi\Controller\Restapi\Model\Country`), hence the error.

To fix this, import the class at the top of the file by adding:

```
use Restapi\Model\Country
```

at the end of the other `use` lines you already have. You can then instantiate the class simply by doing:

```
new Country
```

if you prefer, you could alias it instead:

```
use Restapi\Model\Country as CountryModel
```

then, `new CountryModel` would work.

Alternatively, just changing your existing reference to `use \Restapi\Model\Country` would also fix the error. But don't do this - the main purpose of namespaces is to allow you to use shorter class names in code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i already tried that but it didn't changed a thing.






And further, if i comment the lines that are calling the Country Model, the problem goes on with the TableGateway : 
" Fatal error: Class 'Restapi\Controller\Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway' not found in D:\Web\Code\ZendRest\module\Restapi\src\Restapi\Controller\AdminController.php on line 30"


I agree that the issue is about the namespace, but i don't know where could it come from.

Comment: Sorry it did work fine, i was just wrong using 

$tableGateWay = new Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway

 while using use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;,

Thanks a lot :)